# Counting consecutive values based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to count consecutive staff members (Col D) who service a specific vendor, based on if fees are over 20k (Col G)

I have this formula is Col G and drag it down:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:A2=A2)*($D$2:D2=D2)*($G$2:G2="Yes")*(ROW($G$2:G2)>MAX(IF(($A$2:A2=A2)*($D$2:D2=D2)*($G$2:G2="No"),ROW($G$2:G2)))))}
```

However, this causes an error count when a staff gets repeated on a same client after x years and doesn't reset the count.

[image]

Row 7 should show as 1, not 5.

If someone could help edit this formula to make it reset after another staff is fit between years?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Edward's answer looks fine. Alternative (Excel 2019,O365) :

```
=IFS(G2="No","",OR(AND(G2="Yes",A1&D1<>A2&D2),AND(G2="Yes",SUMPRODUCT((($A$1:A1&$D$1:D1)=A2&D2)*1)=0)),1,AND(G2="Yes",SUMPRODUCT((($A$1:A1&$D$1:D1)=A2&D2)*1)>0),E1+1)
```

Output :
[image: Accum]

[Sheet.v2](https://covid19.framadrop.org/lufi/r/UhGVwevpJw#zsGgycVK+2RmRXl4/hbDLmQI5WtiGL/VdW/VBvT9R+s=)

**EDIT** : For older versions of Excel :

```
=IF(G2="No","",IF(OR(AND(G2="Yes",A1&D1<>A2&D2),AND(G2="Yes",SUMPRODUCT((($A$1:A1&$D$1:D1)=A2&D2)*1)=0)),1,IF(AND(G2="Yes",SUMPRODUCT((($A$1:A1&$D$1:D1)=A2&D2)*1)>0),E1+1)))
```

Comment: when I try go into the code, without making any edits, and press enter (or Ctrl + Shift + Enter) I get a #NAME? error. Same with when I copy your code into my spreadsheet. Do you know why this would occur?

Comment: IFS function is compatible with Excel 2019 and O365. So, it seems you don't have one of these versions. I've edited my answer and uploaded a new file.

Comment: ahh that works, but there is one issue..if a fee ever changes from No to Yes between years, the formula breaks with #VALUE! error

Comment: I changed "" to 0 and it solved it. thank you for your help and time! much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have row 1 without data, like maybe headers. Then in E2 put

```
 =sum(if((A2=A1)*(B2=B1)*(D2=D1)*(G2="Yes")*(DatedIF(C1,C2,"y")=1),E1+1,1))
```

and paste it all the way down.

Comment: I can't put a number (1 into cell E1) into any of the cells as the list is dynamic and changes upon sorting

Comment: so if you have headers that always stay in row 1. Then I can update based on that

Comment: I get a #VALUE! error on the first 4 rows (row 2-5), but it starts working in row 6 (when john doe kicks in)